# No matter what I try, I can not vertically align this

Tags: html, css, text, vertical-alignment

I want to do is vertically align this text, and it has become a huge struggle. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
    <ul id="nav">
        <li>
            <a href="web2home.html">HOME</a>
            <span>See who Matthew H. Goodman is</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="web2cv.html">CV</a>
            <span>View his current Curriculum Vitae</span> 
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">RESEARCH</a>
            <span id="spectab"><a href="#">Current work</a></span>
            <span id="spectab2"><a href="#">Presentations</a></span
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="web2con.html">CONTACT</a>
            <span>Send an email directly to Matthew</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
    #nav li #spectab{
      transition: all 1s;
      position: absolute;
      left: -300px;
      display: block;
      width: 175px;
      background-image: url("http://www.diiiz.com/variant/Argent%C3%A9.jpg"); 
      z-index: -1;
      border-radius: 10px;
      color: white;
      font-size: 20px;
      padding: 0px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: The absolute positioning worries me. I think a demo would be in order.

Comment: Link for the lazy. https://jsfiddle.net/wtv7bgt0/

Comment: last time I posted all of it, I got yelled at by tons of people. Should I post the entire code for the navbar?

Comment: We'd need to see what it is being vertically aligned within, if you could post a complete jsfiddle that illustrates what you're trying to do that'd be helpful

Comment: A decent JSFiddle demo would be optimal

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Snoop2001/q9qgckt2/

Comment: If you are certain that the line of text would not go over one line, and you are certain of the height of the container.  You can simply make the text a line-height the same as the height the container.  and then use vertical-align: middle ...

Comment: If the line of text is more than one line, then it is more complicated.  You have to make the <li> (or the container of the text) display: table and the text itself display: table-cell... then you can use vertical-align: middle on the text.  Read more here.  http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/ (of course, make sure there are no paddings or equal top-bottom padding for vertical-align)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `padding: 15px;`

```
#nav li a:hover {
  color: #778899;
  display: block;
  /* padding: 15px; */
}
```

Add the following rule.

```
#nav li span a {
  padding: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q9qgckt2/1/